# POST angularjs jersey with $resource

Tags: java, angularjs, post, resources, jersey

I'm trying to do post a string (later it will probably be an array or map) to my Jersey application but I can't get it to work.

jersey method :

```
@GET
@javax.ws.rs.Path("/angu/{param}")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public void testAngu(@PathParam("param") String param){

}
```

Angular service:

```
services.factory('testFactory', function ($resource) {
return $resource('/app/api/folders/angu/:param', {}, {
    save: {
        method: 'POST',
        params: {param : '@param'}
    }
})
```

});

Angular controller :

```
app.controller('scanController', ['$scope', 'firstScanFactory', 'testFactory', function ($scope, firstScanFactory, testFactory) {
firstScanFactory.get({}, function (firstScanFactory) {
    $scope.shows = firstScanFactory.listShows;
})

$scope.callJersey = function() {
    testFactory.save("toto");
}
```

}]);

And finally the button for the call :

```
<a class="ls-sc-button default" ng-click="callJersey()">Valider</a>
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: What does not work? Do you get errors? No results? Do you have dumps of the JSON transmitted and what Jersey gets in `param `?

Comment: My angular controller is called but after i don't know. I put a break point in jersey but I never get there. There is probable something wrong with the service or the jersey method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your Jersey-method is annotated with `@GET`, however your Angular code uses `method: 'POST'`.

   Because of that, Jersey will never select `testAngu()` as the matching route.
2. If you use the `@`, you need to pass the parameter as a property of an object. The `@param` string will tell the resource to replace `:param` with the property param on the object you pass it as parameters:

   `testFactory.save({"param": "toto"});`

The [API documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) says:

> If the parameter value is prefixed with @ then the value for that parameter will be extracted from the corresponding property on the data object (provided when calling an action method). For example, if the defaultParam object is {someParam: '@someProp'} then the value of someParam will be data.someProp.

Comment: I change the jersey method :

 `@POST
 @javax.ws.rs.Path("/angu/{param}")
 @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
 public void testAngu(@PathParam("param") String param){
  
 }`

But i still can't debug my method.

Comment: Have you looked at the network tab in the browser developer tools? Is there a POST request? And to which URL?

Comment: Yes, there is a post but i don't see any param in the url.

Request URL:http://localhost:8080/app/api/folders/angu
Request Method:POST
Status Code:404 Not Found
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:8080

Comment: Yes, that's because of `@param` - see my updated answer.